# ngrok - Get all routes to localhost server

Tags: http, routes, server, localhost, ngrok

I'm using ngrok (free account) in my localhost for my coded web server written in Go

In Ubuntu, after starting my server (which listens on port 3000), I run this command to start ngrok:

`./ngrok http 3000`

Then other PC can get access to my demo web by path provided by ngrok, for instance, `http://6fed323a.ngrok.io`

But when they do something on it (for example, click on a button that redirects), the host of URL becomes `localhost` again

There isn't any functions of ngrok that allows access to all routes in server, is there? I'm learning

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue, the reason for this is because your button uses a straight absolute path redirect which ngrok (or any tunneling service ive used so far) cannot handle.  You need to use a relative path redirect such as:
`window.location.href = '/path';`

In general, it is considered best practice to always use relative urls so that the app is not bound to the hostname.  Of course, this is in an ideal work- most legacy apps may not follow this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

While I was working on a Rails app I wanted to run it on **ngrok** but I got error below:

`The connection to http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000.`

It seems like ngrok works fine but my local server is not. Which is true since I forgot to run my rails app first by run `$ rails s`. By doing so I was able to get ngrok tunneing works fine.

Make sure your local server run first.

I have noticed ngrok url changes to localhost url when I click on site logo which is defined as `root_path` in my `route file`. But other links and header tabs for example works fine and shows ngrok url.

Good luck.